# How to get html source code from body field in node type edit form?

Tags: 8, nodes

In node type = "article", I have field of type body.

[image]

**In my .module file, I want to get its raw source code with actual html classes too. But all I get is:**

[image]

```
$body = $node->get('field_all_body')->value;
print_r($body);die;
```

I want the value should contain div class too. How it can be achieved?

My actual requirement is:
I want to populate one field value on behalf of the class exists in `'field_all_body'` field.

Foe example, I select some text in text-editor, and mark it bold, then that particular text should get cloned in another field too.

Answer (score 1):

The basic text format filters out all but a few HTML tags.  You want to select the Full HTML text format to keep your divs and classes.

Comment: I changed the format to full_html but still it won't reflected the classes inside.

Comment: CKEditor might be doing some filtering.  You may have to change it's settings to for the full html filter to allow this.  Alternatively, you can make a filter that does not use CKEditor.  I tend to have a "no change html' filter that is just a text box for this.